# A variable that is read-only after assignment at run-time?

Tags: c++, constants

Fairly new programmer here, and an advance apology for silly questions.

I have an `int` variable in a program that I use to determine what the lengths of my arrays should be in some of my structures. I used to put it in my header as a `const int`. Now, I want to fork my program to give the variable different values depending on the arguments given in, but keep it read-only after I assign it at run-time.

A few ideas I've had to do this. Is there a preferred way?

1. Declare a `const int *` in my header and assigning it to a `const int` in my main function, but that seems clunky.
2. Make it a plain `int` in my main function.
3. Pass the variable as an argument when the function is called.
4. Something else I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: If you are going to use this variable to create arrays of variable size at run time, then this is not Standard C++. Standard C++ does not allow **Variable length arrays(VLA)**. So the length of the array must be a compile time constant.

Comment: @Als: I am creating constant-length arrays, but I am not sure what the length is until run-time.

Comment: @BlueMagister: Then they're not constant-length. "constant" in this context meaning "compile-time constant". You cannot give an array (unless you allocate it with `new`) a non-compile-time size in C++. You have to use either a `std::vector` or allocate it with `new`.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Okay. It appears that the best I can do is create my own class (as suggested in one of the answers), and then allocate these arrays with `new`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use a function-static variable and a simple function. Observe:

```
int GetConstValue(int initialValue = 0)
{
  static int theValue = initialValue;
  return theValue;
}
```

Since this is a function-level static variable, it is initialized only the first time through. So the `initialValue` parameter is useless after the first run of the function. Therefore, all you need to do is ensure that the first call of the function is the one that initializes it.

Answer (score 6):

C++ doesn't have a built-in solution for this, but if you really want to make sure that your int is only assigned once, you can build your own special int class:

```
class MyConstInt
{
public: 
    MyConstInt(): assigned(false) {}
    MyConstInt& operator=(int v)
    {
        assert(!assigned); 
        value = v; 
        assigned = true; 
        return *this; 
    }   
    operator int() const 
    { 
        assert(assigned); 
        return value; 
    }
private: 
    int value; 
    bool assigned; 
}; 


MyConstInt mi; 
//  int i = mi;         //  assertion failure; mi has no value yet
mi = 42; 
//  mi = 43;        //  assertion failure; mi already has a value
int* array = new int[mi];
```

Comment: Instead of a `MyConstInt` I would make it a `MySettings`, but similar concept.  Also, constructable from a value would be a _great_ idea.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: True, but I wanted to show the simplest possible implementation (eg. templating it on the value type would probably also be a good idea).

Comment: I think it's great idea too. Better than the function with `static`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When exactly do you know the correct value? If you read it from a file or whatever, you can just say:

```
const int n = determine_correct_value();
```

Comment: I know the correct value from the arguments passed in. But this construction makes sense. I'll fiddle with my code and see if this works.

Comment: You mean `argv`? It won't work then, sorry. Globals are initialized before control flow enters `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to say that what you want doesn't make sense. A constant is something that *doesn't* change its value, not something that maybe changes its value once or twice. If you want a global variable, just make it non-constant.

On the other hand, if you have scope-constant values, you would just declare and initialize them at the same time, following the general C++ guideline to declare as close to the usage site as possible. For example, mark the use of constants in the following local scope:

```
for (auto it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
  const Foo & x = *it;
  const std::size_t n = x.get_number_of_bars();

  // use x and n ...

  const bool res = gobble(x, zip(n));
  if (res && shmargle(x)) { return 8; }
}
```

Here the compiler may even choose not to generate any special code for the variables at all if their value is already known through other means.

Comment: I was looking for a way to assign a variable once at run-time, but then make it immutable afterwards.