# C++ - Unable to overload assignment operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I am trying to overload the assignment operator but it doesn't seem to work. [The code is based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7880348/3895469). I've searched for other examples of overloading the assignment operator, but it doesn't seem like my code shouldn't run.

This is my code:

```
#pragma once

#include <assert.h>

class ReadOnlyInt
{
public: 
    ReadOnlyInt(): assigned(false) {}

    ReadOnlyInt& operator=(int v);
    operator int() const ;
private: 
    int value; 
    bool assigned; 
}; 

ReadOnlyInt& ReadOnlyInt::operator=(int v)
{
    assert(!assigned); 
    value = v; 
    assigned = true; 
    return *this; 
}   

ReadOnlyInt::operator int() const 
{ 
    assert(assigned); 
    return value; 
}
```

Intellisense doesn't give any warnings, but the `operator=` is not highlighted as a keyword.

Now if I make an assigment, Intellisense does recognize it's not possible:

```
ReadOnlyInt bar = 12;
```

> no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "ReadOnlyInt"

This works however:

```
int foo = bar;
```

## Solution

This question was marked as duplicate, so I can't answer it. This was the solution I came up with based on the comments and answer on this question:

```
ReadOnlyInt::ReadOnlyInt()
: assigned(false)
{}

ReadOnlyInt::ReadOnlyInt(int v)
: value(v), assigned(true)
{}
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `ReadOnlyInt bar` then assign `bar = 12;`

Comment: `ReadOnlyInt bar = 12;` does not do an assignment; it's copy initialization. To use assignment, create the object and **separately** assign to it: `ReadOnlyInt bar; bar = 12;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize and declare at the same time. You need to do this

```
ReadOnlyInt bar;
bar = 12;
```

This is because there is no appropriate constructor for `ReadOnlyInt` that takes an `int` argument.